Monitor changes in one class from another class
I am trying to implement a location tracking app (to log dog walks) and my goal is to have a LocationManager that produces nothing more than the current location as CLLocationCoordinate2D. And I will have a DataManager that handles SwiftData CRUD stuff. And Finally a WalkManager that acts as a ViewModel, getting the current location, adding it to the current Walk, and updating a cameraPosition of type MapCameraPosition that is then used by the map in my WalkScreen. However, I am struggling with getting the WalkManager to be able to monitor changes in the LocationManager. @State won't work, and I am not sure what the current best practice is. I have seen some examples of multiple things to monitor, using Combine and AnyCancelable, but nothing for monitoring just one property of just one class, and if Combine is no longer the best way to do this I don't know that figuring out how to implement for a single property makes sense.
So, to provide a bit of code my LocationManager starts with this
@Observable
final class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @ObservationIgnored private let clManager = CLLocationManager()
    private(set) var rawCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

And the function to update the rawCoordinate is
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    rawCoordinate = locations.last?.coordinate
}

Then, in my WalkManager I have
@Observable
final class WalkManager {
    let locationManager: LocationManager = LocationManager()

And I am trying to figure out how to even monitor locationManager.rawCoordinate for changes.
For what it is worth the property is rawCooridnate because I intend to implement a Kalman filter like this and show both raw and refined paths in my proof of concept, to see if I can get better path results. But that's for later. I need to get one coordinate working first. :)
EDIT: I have also looked into Key-Value Observing but that fails because CLLocationCoordinate2D and Obj-C don't get along. I already need to convert CLLocationCoordinate2D to my own Coordinate2D: Codable struct to be able to use it with SwiftData so I guess if I need to convert to be able to monitor changes too that's not the end of the world. But damn, it seems like this would be something that Swift can do natively. Or is Class to Class communication really not a best practice, and that's why only SwiftUI views get @State?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/observation/withobservationtracking(_:onchange:)

And if you want to support earlier than iOS 17 you can use a Combine Subject or even good old NSNotification which works back to the dark ages. To answer your last question, the only in-built property observation Swift has is didSet/willSet. Everything else depends on a framework.  Only SwiftUI gets @State because @State is part of the SwiftUI framework

Also, in SwiftUI your view is also your view model. It sounds like WalkManager is more of a coordinator. It can subscribe to a subject on your location manager, expose a current location to your views and work with the DataManager to persist data

Your title is confusing "class" and "object".

@paulw11 Yes, trying to get my head around MVVM and how older examples use it a lot and now people seem to be moving away. But my thing is I will have multiple Views that need to show a mad, so duplicating code in those views seems like a bad idea. And I want to separate responsibilities, so LocationManager produces a CLLocatiionCoordinate2D, and WalkManager turns that into something the view can use to present a Map. From a learning perspective didSet seems like a good place to start, but all the examples I have found show internal reactions, not monitoring another class.

didSet is not applicable for observing changes from another object, I was just describing the only thing that is built in to the Swift language.  Everything else comes from a framework. You can use a didSet closure to update a Combine subject or post an NSNotification. You can use MVVM with SwiftUI but your SwiftUi typically is the view model; either holding local state in @State, or accepting state from a parent view via a @Binding or an Observable (typically injected vis the environment).

If you need the same code in multiple places then it would typically either be in a coordinator/model class or you would decompose your view hierarchy into reusable views. For example if you need a map in multiple views then you create a WalkMapView or whatever and reuse that.
